# shell script to pass file names and run through

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have list of file names file1,file2,file3
I want to pass these file names in the script and remove the special characters

I prepared sed command to remove the special characters

```
sed  -i -e 's/^B/,/g' /home/data/nfiledata/ 
hdfs dfs -put -f /home/data/nfiledata/*  user/sai/table1/nfiledata/
gzip  /home/data/nfiledata/*
```

---

```
sed  -i -e 's/^B/,/g' /home/data/marginfile/  
hdfs dfs -put -f /home/data/marginfile/*  user/sai/table2/marginfile/
gzip  /home/data/marginfile/*
```

---

```
sed  -i -e 's/^B/,/g' /home/data/calldata/  
hdfs dfs -put -f /home/data/calldata/*  user/sai/table3/calldata/
gzip  /home/data/calldata/*
```

My question is instead of writing multiple times same command can i write  in one command and loop the process for each file using Shell script

```
nfile = (nfiledata,margindata, calldata)
while IFS= read -r nfile
do
  sed  -i -e 's//,/g' /home/data/$nfile/
  hdfs dfs -put -f /home/data/$nfile/*  user/sai/table$/$nfile/
  gzip  /home/data/$nfile/*
done < "home/data/$nfile"
```

Comment: What are you hoping `sed 's//,/g'` will do?

Comment: `files=( file1 file2 file3 )` is correct array assignment syntax. Can't have whitespace around the `=`s, can't have commas.

Comment: I strongly suggest running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: `sed` normally operates on _files_ not _directories_.  In the code `sed  -i -e 's/^B/,/g' /home/data/file1/ `, what are you expecting `sed` to do?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for original version of question

The same `sed` command can be applied to edit-in-place several files with a single invocation:

```
sed  -i -e 's/old/new/g' /home/data/file1 /home/data/file2 /home/data/file3
```

Also, if the file names really are that simple, then *brace expansion* can be used:

```
sed  -i -e 's/old/new/g' /home/data/file{1..3}
```

Or,

```
sed  -i -e 's/old/new/g' /home/data/file[123]
```

Or, if there are no other similarly named files that you want to exclude, *pathname expansion* may be sufficient:

```
sed  -i -e 's/old/new/g' /home/data/file?
```

#### Example of real file names

```
sed  -i -e 's/old/new/g' nfile_dat fileidentifier margindata calldata
```

Comment: what about `/home/data/file[123]` or `/home/data/file?` ?

Comment: @MaxU Yes.  I didn't show that originally because the OP's it is likely that `file1`, `file2,` etc are just stand-ins and the real file names are more complex.  If not, however, I added your suggestions to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer John. What if my file names are different like (nfile_dat, fileidentifier,margindata,calldata) ? Also how can i loop the data

Comment: @Sai I just added to the answer an example using those file names.

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop, not a `while read` loop, is appropriate here:

```
nfile=(file1 file2 file3)
for f in "${nfile[@]}"; do
  sed  -i -e 's/^B/,/g' /home/data/"$f"/ # should this be "$f"/* ?
  hdfs dfs -put -f /home/data/"$f"/*  user/sai/table1/"$f"/
  gzip /home/data/"$f"/*
done
```

Noteworthy components:

- Assignments must not have spaces around the `=`. Commas are not part of array syntax in bash -- unquoted, unescaped whitespace acts as a separator in that case as elsewhere.
- Expansions such as `$f` must be inside double quotes to be performed safely (without string-splitting or globbing).
- Glob expansions, such as `*`, must be outside quotes to be honored.

Comment: Thank you Charles. Even if my file names are different i can use this script? correct? My file names are like (nfile_dat, fileidentifier,margindata,calldata) . Each file represent a table in my hadoop.

Comment: @Sai, of course; put the actual directory names you want into the array contents. (Your code is written with `file1`, `file2` and `file3` being directory names, not file names; if they are in fact filenames, the original proposed commands wouldn't be correct either because of the trailing `/`s).

Comment: @Sai, ...so, if they're actually files, make it `/home/data/"$f"` where currently written `/home/data/"$f"/*` or `/home/data/"$f"/`.